# Could not load type 'MyApplication.MvcApplication'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This has been asked lots of times, mine seems slightly different.

I've build the web application from a class library, adding the bits I need as I go.

I have a `Global.asax` like this:

```
<%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyApplication.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

and a `Global.asax.cs` like this:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    using System.Web;

    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Do stuff...        
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the application I get the yellow screen:

[image: Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyApplication.MvcApplication'.]

The only changes I've made from the class library template are adding the project type GUIDs to the proj file, installing *Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc* from NuGet and referencing *System.Web*.

Any suggestions?

I've tried the rebuilding, deleting and re-adding etc.

**Framework** : .Net Framework v4.6

**Update**

I've been chiselling at the Web Application template, deleting everything that's there that's not in my project.  The NuGet packages are identical and have the same versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

The `Web.Config` is also identical:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No, I do have `Global.asax` & `Global.asax.cs`  Good eyes though!

Comment: Did you make sure that this `Global.asax.cs` class that you have is compiled to an assembly that resides in the `bin` folder of your web application? At runtime, that's where ASP.NET will look for an assembly containing this class.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Both are set to Build Action = Compile and Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy.

Comment: Well, use a reflector and checkout your `bin` folder - that would be the ultimate proof.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Just checked the assembly and it is there.

Comment: And you checked that it contains a class called `MyApplication.MvcApplication`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Aye, I can see the `MyApplication` namespace, `MvcAppliation` class and the `Application_Start()` method in that.

Comment: It looks like your web server is running different code from what you might think. If you are using IIS Express, go to the properties of your web application, navigate to the `Web` tab, click on the `Create Virtual Directory` button, clean your project, rebuild and run again. You could manually clean your `bin` folder beforehand.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Just tried that, still the same result.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Just tried the same with 'Full Fat' IIS and the same error is showing there too.

Comment: OK, this is strange. I would start from a blank ASP.NET app and progressively add stuff until the problem is isolated.

Comment: Why are you starting from class library rather than a web app template?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm currently chiselling things off the web template to see if I can replicate it.  Thanks for the help so far.  If you have any epiphanies  then let me know!

Comment: @timothyclifford Just because I want to know how it all fits together.

Comment: @BanksySan - I appreciate your idea sir but it is advisable to start with a web template.  There might be some information missing since you started from a class library.  MVC templates are different and we can create windows services from a class library but it is difficult to create one that runs with iis.  For example, MVC uses action based routing and other functionalities that is difficult to implement from a class library. Very Nerdy idea though :)

Comment: @staticvoidmain Thanks for the advise, but the point of the exercise to do just that.  Find out what those issues are and find out what's in a web template all together.

Comment: In that case, why don't you create a blank web app project then use a diff tool to look at all the differences. Adding project type IDs to project files manually sounds error prone to me.

Comment: @timothyclifford That would pretty much defeat the object, the point is to figure out what's special about web projects.

Comment: Clean your solution , Rebuild your web project and try again

Comment: @Shyju Did that, also tried closing all the instances of Visual Studio and ever rebooting in case there was something hanging about.  I've also tried deleting the temporary ASP.NET files.

Comment: @BanksySan I disagree, this would tell you exactly what the difference is between your current project and the web app template. Otherwise you're going to continue with the trial and error approach.

Comment: @timothyclifford Sorry, misread what you wrote!  My bad, yes, I am trying that exact thing.  I'm working through the proj file now trying to see if I can dig out the magic code.